# Exception BeanFactory must be set on AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect to access qualified executor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-annotations

I created a public method with @Async and I also have a bean for that class in which this method is created. But when I am calling it , it is not behaving async and getting blocked. Then I created a executor in application-bean and used @Async(value = “executorname”), even this is not working and on every call I am getting “beanFactory must be set on AnnotationasyncExecutionAspect to access qualified executor”.

in my application bean.xml I have 
there are then few executors and schedulers and I want to use one new executor.

Please tell me how to get away with this error and get async behaviour
Thanks in advance

Comment: please post relevant code snippet and config files.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing exactly the same issue and find out a solution I hope works for you (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10276).

Apparently if you unabled Spring's AspectJ aspects into your project (by using aspectj-maven-plugin, for instance), Spring's Async mechanism can be placed twice in your bean, one by aspectj and other by proxy.  But, since it doesn't know it, AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect will not be injected with a BeanFactory and you will see the assertion exception you had.

To fix it, you must instruct Spring's Async mechanism to use the AspectJ support.  Do this incluing this in your Application Context.

```
<task:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"/>
```

I hope I could be of any help.

Comment: Thanks, I have added this and its still not working. Will put sample code shortly

Answer (score 3):

For annotation based configuration you can use `@EnableAsync(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)`